# Существует ли модель, которая предсказывает по параметрам продажи, но при этом зависит от времени

Tags: python, model

Всем привет,
Существует ли такая модель, которая может предсказать по параметрам значение ( как Random Forest) , но при этом во времени тоже предсказывает , как ARIMA?
То есть в моем дата сере много параметров от которых зависят продажи и нужно предсказать по неделям на будущий год. Пишу на питоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, такие модели есть. И есть их много всякий разновидностей. Очень их полюбляют изучать в эконометрике. Можете брать любой учебник с этим словом в загаловке, и почит наверняка там будут такие модели. Ну например:

В.П.Носко Эконометрика Введение в регрессионный анализ временных рядов
И.С.Светуньков Методы и модели социально-экономического прогнозирования
и т.д.
Или на сайтах:
https://studylib.ru/doc/186527/metodicheskie-ukazaniya-po-postroeniyu-var-modelej
https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/11
https://otexts.com/fpp2/VAR.html
https://analyticsindiamag.com/hands-on-tutorial-on-vector-autoregressionvar-for-time-series-modeling/
https://www.aptech.com/blog/introduction-to-the-fundamentals-of-vector-autoregressive-models/
тут даже с примерами на Python:
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/vector-autoregression-examples-python/

Вообще, ищите по ключевым словам "Векторная Авторегрессионная модель",
"Модель распределенного лага", "Система одновременных уравнений" -  в зависимости от особенностей именно ваших рядов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!